# Resize canvas dynamically generates blank canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I´m trying dynamically adjust the size of my canvas depending on the number of images, which will be drawn.

For only one image it works perfectly. If I have more than one image, the canvas is blank.

`this.imageWidth` gives me the width of the 1st image), and `this.heightCanvas` gives me the total height of all images.

Because, I want to place all images in a vertical row.

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvasWrapper"></div>
```

**JS**

```
  startCanvas() {
  var canvasExists = document.getElementById('ocrCanvas');

  if (canvasExists != null) {
    alert(canvasExists);
    var myNode = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }
  }
  var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  canv.id = 'ocrCanvas';
  document.getElementById('canvasWrapper').appendChild(canv); // adds the canvas to #someBox

  const getContext = () => document.getElementById('ocrCanvas').getContext('2d');
  const ctx = getContext();
  ctx.canvas.width  = this.imageWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = this.heightCanvas;

  console.log('ctx width' + ctx.canvas.width)
  console.log('ctx height' + ctx.canvas.height)

  this.fillCanvas();

}

fillCanvas() {
const getContext = () => document.getElementById('ocrCanvas').getContext('2d');

const loadImage = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`load ${url} fail`));
    img.src = url;
  });
};

const depict = options => {
  const ctx = getContext();
  ctx.canvas.width  = this.imageWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = this.heightCanvas;

  console.log('ctx width' + ctx.canvas.width)
  console.log('ctx height' + ctx.canvas.height)

  const myOptions = Object.assign({}, options);
  return loadImage(myOptions.src).then(img => {

    ctx.drawImage(img, myOptions.x, myOptions.y);
  });
};

const imgs = this.base64Canvas;
imgs.forEach(depict);
};
```

Comment: Yes setting the width or height of your canvasElement clears everything from its context. That's unclear why you set it at every image.

Comment: Ok thx, so I have to set the size just before drawing the images?

Comment: Yes, but do it only once.

Comment: I tried to create/remove a canvas just prior drawing the images. But the canvas still remains blank

Comment: That´s strange, because I draw the images on a completely new canvas afterwards

Comment: Any ideas? I create a complete new canvas with new dimensions and draw it completely new. But it is blank

Comment: I found the problem. I drawing images from the iphone on the canvas. But they are to large (height), if I draw more than one image. So I´ve to resize it prior drawing the canvas and now it works